# Trouble installing basemap for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I try to install basemap for python.

I installed the Geometry Engine like this:

```
export GEOS_DIR=/usr/local
./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR
make; make install
```

Then I installed PROJ4-9-1 like this:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

That all seems good. At least, there were no errors popping up.
Then I tried to install basemap via

```
python setup.py install
```

Which gave me an error - permission denied (and a lot of other errors like these:

```
src/_geoslib.c:6023:34: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_AsSignedChar' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE signed char __Pyx_PyInt_AsSignedChar(PyObject* x) {

                             ^
src/_geoslib.c:6042:35: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_AsSignedShort' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE signed short __Pyx_PyInt_AsSignedShort(PyObject* x) {

                       ^
src/_geoslib.c:6061:33: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_AsSignedInt' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE signed int __Pyx_PyInt_AsSignedInt(PyObject* x) {
```

or

```
/usr/local/include/geos_c.h:500:71: note: passing argument to parameter 's' here
extern GEOSGeometry GEOS_DLL *GEOSGeom_createPoint(GEOSCoordSequence* s);
```

or

```
src/_geoslib.c:5339:12: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void (char *, char *)' to parameter of type 'GEOSMessageHandler' (aka 'void (*)(const char *, ...)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
initGEOS(__pyx_f_8_geoslib_notice_h, __pyx_f_8_geoslib_error_h);
```

So, since the last error was:

```
running install_lib
copying build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/_geoslib.so -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so: Permission denied
```

I typed in

```
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

which did not give me any errors. The last lines were these

```
running install_egg_info
Writing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/basemap-1.0.7-py2.7.egg-info
running install_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
```

But, importing basemap in python2.7 gives me this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named basemap
```

Obviously, it did not install it...
Any ideas why?

Comment: Found any solution to this problem?

Comment: @alphacentauri nope. I ended up not using it. I had the GDAL framework already installed through the QGIS installation. I tried to force the installation of basemap through and ended up with destroying some libraries etc (one was the GDAL framework). In the end I had to use a back up of my computer to restore my old system in order to get my installed libraries and frameworks to run again.. Nasty.